# Whether Alljoyn can be used in factory environment or not?

Tags: alljoyn

I want use Alljoyn to communicate between devices in smart factory.
However,it seems there is no such use cases not yet.
So,i want to know if Alljoyn can't be used in factory for some technical reasons,
for instance,stability or performance.

In my case, I need device can communicate directly.
So,publish-subscribe-based protocol,like MQTT,wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the specific problem of your case. But I'm going to answer anyway.

AllJoyn runs on the proximal network (local network) by using **Wi-Fi, Ethernet or Power Line (PLC)**. And AllJoyn does not require a cloud to function, cloud network connection is optional. It works in your case as long as the local network functions properly.

```
Transport name          Value   Description

TRANSPORT_NONE          0x0000  No transport.
TRANSPORT_LOCAL         0x0001  The local transport.
TRANSPORT_TCP           0x0004  Transport using TCP as the underlying mechanism.
TRANSPORT_UDP           0x0100  Transport using UDP as the underlying mechanism.
TRANSPORT_EXPERIMENTAL  0x8000  Select a release-specific experimental transport.
TRANSPORT_IP            0x0104  Allow the system to decide between TCP or UDP.
TRANSPORT_ANY           0x0105  Allow the system to choose any appropriate transport.
```

AllJoyn supports both [TCP/IP and UDP/IP transport mechanisms](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/learn/core/system-description/alljoyn-transport#alljoyn-transportmask-definition). While developing your app, you can decide to use which transport mechanism you want. 
AllJoyn documentation states that;

> If an AllJoyn application desires to only use TCP as the underlying
>   layer 4 mechanism, it can do so by specifying TRANSPORT_TCP in
>   advertisement, discovery and Session join and bind options.

As TCP guarantees all sent network packages will reach their destination in the correct order. In your case you can choose TCP communication as a more reliable option.